# How to Show Product thumbnail (picture) in Sales -> Orders Grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have been able to add custom attribute to the orders grid but do not know how to render sold product thumbbnail.
How to show product picture on the `Sales -> Orders` grid?

So when a product is sold it would be great to see its picture next to the product SKU in the `Sales -> Orders` grid. 
So when my friend helps me to pack all the orders, he can see how the product looks like and he can easily identify it.

**Any Idea?**

Comment: Do you want to show product image in frontend or backend?

Comment: Backend in sales orders grid...

Comment: Hi this is what you want.  
https://www.screencast.com/t/KlpfPod4

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same, So share my code hope it helps

First, create a sample module and follow below instruction. Consider here Packagename of the module is   Stackoverflow_Answer

Add below dependency in etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stackoverflow_Answer" setup_version="0.0.2">
         <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create a vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">

                    <item name="image" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Image</item>
                    <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                    <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                    <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                    <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                    <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                    <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                    <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                    <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                    <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments> 
            <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">

                        <item name="image" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-image</item>
                        <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                        <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                        <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                        <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                        <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                        <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                        <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                        <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create etc/di.xml and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer">
        <plugin name="order-view-image" type="Stackoverflow\Answer\Plugin\DefaultRendererPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin/DefaultRendererPlugin.php and add below code

```
<?php
namespace Stackoverflow\Answer\Plugin;

use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;

class DefaultRendererPlugin {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
    */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @param ImageHelper      $imageHelper
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        ImageHelper $imageHelper
    )
    {
        $this->imageHelper      = $imageHelper;
    }

    public function aroundGetColumnHtml(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $defaultRenderer, \Closure $proceed,\Magento\Framework\DataObject $item, $column, $field=null) {

                if($column === 'image') {
            $img = $this->imageHelper->init($item->getProduct(), 'small_image')->setImageFile($item->getProduct()->getImage())->resize(200)->getUrl();
            $result = '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$item->getName().'" />';
        }
        else {
            if($field) {
                $result = $proceed($item,$column,$field);
            }
            else {
                $result = $proceed($item,$column);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

It will display same result as mentioned in below link
screencast.com/t/KlpfPod4

This is for order grid as we discussed

Create sales_order_grid.xml under "SR\MagentoCommunity\view\adminhtml\ui_component" and put or append below code.

```
<column name="product_skus_for_image" class="SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Productimage">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="Component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">product Image</item>
                        </item>
   </argument>
</column>
```

Next step. create Productimage.php under "SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\" and put below code.

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;

class Productimage extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * ItemLocation constructor.
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */

    protected $_imageHelper;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        Image $imageHelper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
         $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

          foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if($item) {
                    if($item['product_skus_for_image']) {
                       $allSkus =  explode("|",$item['product_skus_for_image']);
                       $allProductImage = '';
                       foreach($allSkus as $sku)
                       { 
                         $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
                         if($product) { 
                              $img = $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'small_image')->setImageFile($product->getImage())->resize(200)->getUrl();
                           $allProductImage .='<img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$product->getName().'" />';
                           }
                       }
                       $item['product_skus_for_image'] = $allProductImage;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

create di.xml under SR/MagentoCommunity/etc and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="join_sales_order_grid_with_product"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

</config>
```

Create CollectionFactory.php (plugin file) at SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider and paste below code.

```
    <?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OrderGridCollection;

class CollectionFactory
{
    public function afterGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        $collection,
        $requestName
    ) {
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            if ($collection instanceof OrderGridCollection) {
                $collection->getSelect()
                    ->join(
                        $collection->getTable('sales_order_item'),
                        'main_table.entity_id = '.$collection->getTable('sales_order_item').'.order_id',
                        [
                                                          'product_skus_for_image' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "|")'),
                        ]
                    )

                    ->join(
                            $collection->getTable('sales_order'),
                            'main_table.entity_id = '.$collection->getTable('sales_order').'.entity_id',
                            [
                            'product_shipping' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order`.shipping_description SEPARATOR "|")'),

                            ]
                    )


                    ->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')
                    ->group('main_table.entity_id');
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Run setup:upgrade and flush cache.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I have tried to create module you have posted here, but its seems this is not working, it is not even change the sales order grid ( something must missing from the code)
I have also tried to implement it into my own existing custom sales order grid without any luck. I believe that the PHP part of your module is what I looking for. I just can't render the image into the grid.

Comment: @peter, Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article, maybe it works
https://magecomp.com/blog/display-product-image-backend-order-detail-page-magento-2/

First, we need to create custom column and call our code to display product image. app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml

Now we need to create default.phtml file which contains our logic of showcasing product image.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml

Click the link of the article to see the code.

Comment: Be aware that one reader has reported a bug with the code in this article - that If the admin deletes a product then the order can't open.